# Wi-fi is auto-enabling

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, motorola-droid

I don't know why but the Wi-fi on my Droid (Froyo) keeps auto-enabling. I can't figure out what is causing it and want to make it stop. I only like being connected to wi-fi at times of actual use so I don't waste battery.

Anybody think of applications/settings that can be configured to auto-enable wi-fi?

Comment: I have found the culprit but I still don't know where to look to change the settings, these things get enabled when I used my desk dock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for an application titled 'Power Manager', this application has controls to enable/disable: WIFI, Bluetooth, GPS based off multiple triggers. One of which being powered by A/C which was what my 'issue' was. Just had to change this so it didn't change the WiFi status.

Answer (score 2):

What about rebooting your device ?

I had the same problem solved like this...

[EDIT] Do you use a widget for the wifi: it can help you to disable it?

Comment: rebooting fixes sooooo many problems.

Comment: I wish I knew how to recreate this issue rather than just a generic 'it happens sometimes', would make troubleshooting this issue a lot easier.

Comment: does rebooting fixes your problem ?

Comment: no, rebooting has not solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of apps that re-enable wifi: can you share your appbrain app-list? It would be easier for us to tell.

Comment: http://www.appbrain.com/user/cynicaljoy/apps-on-the-phone

Comment: Juice-defender, Ultimate Juice, Power Manager Full -- one of these is likely to be the culprit. I can't speak from direct experience, because I've intentionally avoided these apps, but the general sentiment is that they are a bad idea, because they lead to odd phenomena such as you are experiencing. I'm not saying that they are always a bad idea, or that they can't be used without ill-effect, but they do tend to monkey with processes that are better controlled by other means. You might want to try without them for a bit, see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I've disabled (uninstalled) those applications and will attempt to run without for a few days. Will update with results.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by auto enabling? Does it get enabled every time you unlock your phone? Otherwise did you try changing this option: Settings->Wireless and Networks-> Wi-Fi settings (press menu key) Advanced -> Wi-Fi sleep policy

(I have Android 2.1, so your menu path may differ slightly)

Comment: Auto enable meaning that I manually disable the wi-fi and the device turns it back on without my specific direction. This wouldn't be the sleep policy as that would be what turns it off. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sprint, go to *Settings → Wireless and Network/More... → Mobile Networks* and uncheck the box *Connections optimizer*.